# Please help me with a vacancy announcement

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

I'm writing a vacancy announcement in English, and I want to express that whoever gets the job is supposed to work primarily in the workplace. Now I'm wondering:

(i) how I best refer to 'whoever gets the job' (I'm looking for a less informal expression here)

and

(ii) how I best express that the person in question is expected to spend most of their working time at the workplace (the job as such is possible to perform anywhere, hence this perhaps rather odd specification).

Are there fixed idiomatic phrases I could use here? Any and all suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: **The candidate selected for employment will be expected to work onsite most of the time** or **during most working hours**.  vacancy sounds like real estate to me. Perhaps you mean filling a position.

Comment: @Lambie: that sounds like an answer; although I would also suggest usage of "primarily", if Helen is trying to be less informal.

Comment: Or _the successful candidate_.

Comment: @Lambie I thought it was called "vacancy announcement"? Like a more formal word for "job ad"? Thank you all three of you for excellent input!

Comment: @sharur So: "...will be expected to work primarily onsite." Or...?

Comment: If you say there is a vacant position, it implies a set number of things. I'd say: job opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put in the advert something like

> The successful candidate will based at our office in York
> The successful candidate will be expected to work on-site but some travel and home working may be involved
> The successful candidate will be expected to work on-site

Depending on how much time is shared between venues.

In a less formal environment you could replace the successful candidate with you

Incidentally vacancy is used in that sense in the UK but I am not sure about other countries.

Comment: home working? Or working at home?

Comment: @Lambie or working from home. In fact now I think about it WFH is the usual abbreviation.

Comment: Thank you so much, mdewey! Thanks also for clarifying the use of "vacancy" – @Lambie do you speak American English?

Comment: If you are dealing with high-level jobs, one doesn't say vacancy.